# Python ETL behaves differently in Local and Server

Tags: python-3.x, etl

The scenario is if there is any document uploaded from UI, it saves the document in 1 DB table with required information. Later ETL process sync another DB table.

I have a ETL setup in Python, which sets the "state"=1(which is expected) in the source DB but not in destination.

The issue is, when I upload the document with keeping PDB(python debugger) in the server or VS code debugger in local, the columns and its value are stored as expected. But as soon as I make it run without debugger, columns are not synced as required and state is saved as null.

The SQL query that works with debugger is:

```
        SELECT
            d.id as id, 
            d.external_storage_id as external_storage_id, 
            COALESCE(ds.name, 'active') as document_state
        FROM
            documents as d
        LEFT JOIN
            document_states as ds
        ON ds.id = d.state_id
        WHERE
            d.services_db_id = %s
        AND
            d.external_storage_type_id = (SELECT id FROM document_external_storage_type_enums WHERE name = %s)

        cursor.execute(GET_DOCUMENT_ID_QUERY,
                       (services_db_id, storage_type.value,))
```

I tried to

1. Add time.sleep(3) before the cursor.execute
2. Add state=1 static, if `state=null`.

It works in both the tried method but doesnt seems to be a good way to achieve.

Please can anyone suggest, what might be the issue, why its working fine in debugger and not normally?